# Local PHP Rewrite Engine

Tags: php, .htaccess, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am currently developing a PHP Website with PhpStorm and have linked it to XAMPP's PHP interpreter for local testing.

The problem is, that I have eliminated the `.php` extensions in the URL with .htaccess, meaning that locally, the links don't work, since I'm linking like this now `href="page"` and not `href="page.php`.

Is there a setting option, perhaps in PhpStorm or in XAMPP's interpreter, to solve this?

Comment: If you don't want to link to `page.php`, you should not link to it. How should your IDE determine which links are valid and which are not?

Comment: Where it does not work **exactly**? Warning in PhpStorm .. or in the browser? Give an example of such URL that does not work (what you see in a browser's address bar). Right now it's not super clear what exactly you are complaining about (and if it's something that PhpStorm cannot do .. or you simply failed to configure it properly etc).